# Elastic search term filter is not working

Tags: json, elasticsearch

This is my elastic search query for fetching the **id**

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test-index2/business/_search -d'
 {
     "query" : {
         "filtered" : { 
             "query" : {
                 "match_all" : {} 
             },
             "filter" : {
                 "term" : { 
                     "_id" : "AU6LqK0WCSY7HKQGengx"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }'
```

And this is part of the response

```
{"contactNumber": "+1-415-392-3702", "name": "Golden Gate Hotel"}
```

I've got the **contactNumber** and **name**

Now my second query -> i'm querying for the above contact number using term filter

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/test-index2/business/_search -d'
 {
     "query" : {
         "filtered" : { 
             "query" : {
                 "match_all" : {} 
             },
             "filter" : {
                 "term" : { 
                     "contactNumber" : "+1-415-392-3702"
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 }'
```

and i've got **0 hits!**

I've indexed both the contactNumber and name field.

What am i doing wrong??

I should be getting the exact same record back

**Edit:**

Attaching the mapping for contact number

```
{"test-index2":{"mappings":{"business":{"properties":{"address":{"type":"string"},"contactNumber":{"type":"string","store":true},"name":{"type":"string"}}}}}}
```

Comment: What is the mapping for `contactNumber`?

Comment: @AndreiStefan edited to add the mapping for contact number

Comment: `contactNumber` should have an `analyzer` that doesn't change its content, for example `keyword` or it should be `not_analyzed`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`term` filter doesn't analyze the input text, meaning if you search for "+1-415-392-3702" then this is the exact text it's expecting to find in the index.

But, your field being just the default `string` this means it most probably uses the `standard` analyzer for analyzing it. This means that in the index you'll have these tokens: `"1","3702","392","415"` and not a single `+1-415-392-3702`.

So, you need either one of these two:

```
    "contactNumber": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed",
      "store":true
    }
```

or

```
    "contactNumber": {
      "type": "string",
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "store":true
    }
```

Comment: Hello Andrei, Do you have a recommendation for a frontend for elasticsearch. i'm looking to create/update mappings and indices often and it's time consuming to do it via a REST client each time

Comment: Not quite. For testing - Marvel's Sense dashboard, or use one of the clients (Java, Python etc.) but the latter involves some code writing.